# Is there an easy way to route an entire controller to a site root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know how to route a page to a site root, and how to individually specify routes for every single page and action, but I feel like I am creating unnecessary work for myself at times by doing this. Is it possible to make it so that `example.com/method` always equates to `some_controller#method`?

Something like:

```
root "some_controller#index"
controller :some_controller do
    get "/:method" => :method
end
```

instead of

```
root "some_controller#index"
controller :some_controller do
    get "/" => :index, as: :index
    get "/contact" => :contact, as: :contact
    get "/photos" => :photos, as: :photos
    ...
end
```

or is that the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close already:

```
controller :some_controller do
  get ":controller/:action"
end
```

`:controller/:action` will dynamically match the `:action` segment to a method of that name on the controller referenced by the symbol passed to the `controller` method.

I would be careful about security here. Take note on what methods your controller inherits from its parent class (probably ApplicationController), as any public methods will be accessible using this routing style.

Comment: Yes, it is ActionController. Is there danger there?

Comment: It depends what you've defined on your ApplicationController. You can also read the section on [bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) from the rails routing guide for more info.

Comment: You can get a list of accessible methods in the console using `SomeController.action_methods`. I don't think anything outside that list will be accessible.

Comment: Excellent. I marked your answer as accepted - because it was pretty easy to figure out what I needed from there, but the exact answer to my question was actually `get "/:action"` rather than `get "/:controller/:action"` My question was a bit vague though. Thanks!